# What indication will appear in case of one of A320 LGCIU is inoperative?

Tags: landing-gear, autothrust, ecam

What indication and where it will appear in case of one of LGCIU (landing gear control and interface unit) is inoperative?

Comment: Could you maybe explain what LGCIU is and what aircraft you are talking about? I assume **A320 Landing Gear Control Interface Unit** since that is what shows up first on Google, but we cannot be sure.

Comment: you a right, yes a320, thank you. I've added the info

Answer (score 1):

[image: ECAM "WHEEL" page LGCIU]

[enter link description here](http://www.a320dp.com/A320_DP/landing-gear/sys-12.2.0.html)

A320 ECAM "WHEEL" page

The answer:
The LGCIUs (landing gear control and interface unit) receive position information from the landing gear, cargo doors, and landing flap systems and process gear and door position, sequencing, control, and gear lever selection.

When one of two LGCIU is inoperative (№6) amber XXXs in the triangle - indicates that one LGCIU has failed.

...
Source: http://www.a320dp.com/A320_DP/landing-gear/sys-12.2.0.html

Comment: Could you provide attribution for the image?